# Numpy: Efficient way to create a complex array from two real arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, memory-efficient

I have two real arrays (`a` and `b`), and I would like create a complex array (c) which takes the two real arrays as its real and imaginary parts respectively.

The simplest one would be

```
c = a + b * 1.0j
```

However, since my data size is quite large, such code is not very efficient.

We can also do the following,

```
c = np.empty(data_shape)
c.real = a
c.imag = b
```

I am wondering is there a better way to do that (e.g. using `buffer` or something)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's wrong with those?

Comment: As my array size is very larger, the above way is relatively slow. I am wondering whether I can directly initialize the complex array from the data in a and b without much copy

Comment: `c` has to have its own data buffer, interleaving the real and imag values.  `c.dtype` is `complex128`

Answer (score 1):

Since the real and imaginary parts of each element have to be contiguous, you will have to allocate another buffer to interleave the data no matter what. The second method shown in the question is therefore about as efficient as you're likely to get. One alternative would be

```
np.stack((a, b), axis=-1).view(np.complex).squeeze(-1)
```

This works for any array shape, not just 1D. It ensures proper interleaving by stacking along the last dimension in C order.

This assumes that your datatype is `np.float`. If not, either promote to float (e.g. `a = a.astype(float)`), or possibly change `np.complex` to something else.